# Make Gridview Hyperlink field visibility depending on data

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, data-binding

I have a Hyperlink  in a Gridview which is supposed to only be visible when there is a document present.

I know if there's a document present through the field `DocumentExists` which I'm passing through it as part of the DataBinding process.

My HyperlinkField looks like this:

```
<asp:HyperLinkField DataNavigateUrlFields="DocumentID" Visible='<%# Eval("DocumentExists")%>' HeaderText="Document" Text="Download" DataNavigateUrlFormatString="~/KeyTracking/DownloadDocument.aspx?ID={0}" />
```

I foundthe "Eval" part of the code from another SO answer.

However when I run it, I get the following error:

> Databinding expressions are only supported on objects that have a DataBinding event. System.Web.UI.WebControls.HyperLinkField does not have a DataBinding event. Databinding expressions are only supported on objects that have a DataBinding event. System.Web.UI.WebControls.HyperLinkField does not have a DataBinding event.

How can I get this to work?

Comment: Please add code for the rowdatabound event of the gridview then I will give you a solution.

Comment: I'm not changing anything in the RowDataBound event, and I was hoping to do it without needing to override the RowDataBound

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution.

Instead of using a HyperLinkField, use an Item Template which has a hyperlink. Then the Eval will work well.

```
<asp:TemplateField>
     <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:HyperLink runat="server" ID="hf" Visible='<%# Eval("DocumentExists")%>' Text="Download"  NavigateUrl='<%# Eval("DocumentID") %>'/>
     </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```